# SpringBoot: How to convert snake case to camelCase

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I am in a project where we use SpringBoot with Java (1.8 LTS) and Kafka through Spring Cloud Stream.
I get an event through cloud stream, which I persist to mongoDB.

My `StreamListener` looks like this:

```
@StreamListener(MessagingChannels.BLA_CHANNEL)
public void onIncomingEvent(
EventContent eventContent,
@Header(name = uuid) UUID messageId
) {
    doStuffWith(eventContent);
}
```

`EventContent` looks like this:

```
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@JsonNaming
public class EventContent {
private final String dataString1;
private final String dataString2;
...
private final Object details;
}
```

My problem is, that the details object can vary, there can be other key/value pairs by producer.
Some producers send their data in snake_case, but I want to persist it consistently in camelCase.
So `@JsonNaming` does this quiet good, but sadly not transitive for details object.

It's important to be fault tolerant here, so if something breaks here, it should be sent to DLQ.

Does someone have a clue how I do this? Maybe there is an easy way with one spring magic annotation, I don't know - new to spring :)

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You should configure two different objectMappers: one for Kafka with
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
and another for MongoDB without this option.